# Looking for works comparing Moses and St. Paul

Tags: reference-request, paul-apostle, moses, typology

I've been reading the Epistles of St. Paul while doing Exodus 90, so kind of oddly going though both Exodus and the Pauline Epistles I've noticed some similarities:

Moses and Paul were chosen by God for a particular mission, that's not exactly unique in the Bible, but they both:

1. Moses and Paul were 'citizens' of different nation
2. Moses and Paul killed someone and went into exile
3. Moses and Paul had problems speaking, but wrote eloquently
4. Moses and Paul encountered God and something happened to their faces

Those are just four things I thought of off-hand and I'd like to know more.  It's always seemed like New Testament characters needed more OT Types. And I'd like to know if there is anything to this notion.

Comment: Also, [both Moses and Paul wished that all God's people may prophesy](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/62507/38524).

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I thought [my answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/88746/10672) showed that Moses did not actually wanted everyone to prophesy?

Comment: Found a [list 26 comparison](https://www.bible.ca/prophecy/Messianic-prophecy-Moses-Apostle-Paul-Christ-types-shadows-antitypes-similarities-comparisons-1446BC-AD36.htm): not scholarly or methodical but good enough to generate ideas and brainstorming.  Although as you probably know already that it is usually Jesus who is considered the antitype of Moses.  Both confronted hard hearted Israel, do miracles, give commandments, inaugurate covenants, prophets, and both lead the people out from the old enslaved world.

Answer (score 2):

You want works comparing Moses and Paul. Here are some works for you to read:

- Moses and Paul, the Dispensers of the law and Grace: [http://www.biblical-data.org/BOX/Moses_Paul_Stam.pdf#:~:text=The%20writings%20of%20Moses%20are%2C%20to%20be%20sure%2C,God%20-given%20authority%20over%20the%20people%20of%20Israel](http://www.biblical-data.org/BOX/Moses_Paul_Stam.pdf#:%7E:text=The%20writings%20of%20Moses%20are%2C%20to%20be%20sure%2C,God%20-given%20authority%20over%20the%20people%20of%20Israel).
- Moses as a Type of Apostle Paul: Scripture writers: A list of 26 similarities, 2 Corinthians 3; Colossians 2:17, and Comparison Chart of 26 Moses/Paul Shadows, Types, Antitypes and Similarities: https://www.bible.ca/prophecy/Messianic-prophecy-Moses-Apostle-Paul-Christ-types-shadows-antitypes-similarities-comparisons-1446BC-AD36.htm

List of 26 Moses/Paul Shadows and Antitypes

“Shadow of what was to come, but the substance belongs to Christ” Col 2:17

Moses/Paul

> Both were chosen from birth for a special divine purpose: Ex 2:5, Gal
> 1:15
>
> Both were outsiders, "Trojan Horses" who were brought into highest
> inner circle: Ex 2:6, Acts 5:34; 21:39; 22:3, 25–29
>
> Both had Kings who tried to kill them: Ex 1:22; 2:15, 2 Cor 11:32–33
>
> Both escaped death through a woven basket: Ex 2:3, 2 Cor 11:32–33
>
> Both received the top education the world had to offer: Ex 2:10; Acts
> 7:22, Acts 22:3; Phil 3:6
>
> Both proved their faith by works before being commissioned by God: Ex
> 2:11, Acts 22:4-5
>
> Both murdered someone immediately before their conversions: Ex 2:12,
> Acts 7:58; 9:1-2
>
> Both were rejected by their brethren as a deliverers and saviors: Acts
> 7:25, Acts 9:23-26; 22:18
>
> Both talked to God after seeing a bright light in the wilderness: Ex
> 3:2-3, Acts 9:3
>
> Both asked God, “who are you” and God replied, "I AM": Ex 3:13–14,
> Acts 22:8
>
> Both immediately fled to Mt. Sinai and received instruction: Ex 2:15;
> Heb 11:27, Gal 1:17
>
> Both received instructions directly from God on the law at Mt. Sinai:
> Acts 7:38, Gal 1:15–17
>
> Both were law givers who wrote major sections of scripture:
> Pentateuch: 5 OT books, 14 NT books
>
> Both rejected earthly riches, position, and prestige for heavenly
> treasures: Heb 11:26, Phil 3:4-8
>
> Fellow Hebrews rejected the message of truth and salvation: Acts 7:39,
> Acts 18:4–6
>
> Both had fellow Jews who chose slavery and bondage over freedom and
> salvation: Ex 14:11–12; Num 14:3–4, Gal 4:25; 5:1–4
>
> Both performed spectacular and extraordinary miracles: Acts 7:36, Acts
> 19:11–12
>
> Both had speech impediments but produced powerful and impressive
> written documents: Ex 4:10, 2 Cor 10:10
>
> Both were physically affected after they saw God: 2 Cor 3:7–8, 2 Cor
> 12:4–7
>
> Both repeatedly asked God for a request, but both were denied: Deut
> 3:25-26, 2 Cor 12:2-10
>
> Paul removed the “mystery veil” of Moses by teaching about the glory
> of Jesus Christ: Ex 34:33–35, 2 Cor 3:12–18; Eph 3:1–6; Rom 16:25–27;
> Col 2:1–3
>
> Writing on stone vs. spirit: Ex 24:12; 2 Cor 3:7, 2 Cor 3:2-3
>
> Both endured persecution by stoning from fellow Hebrews they were
> trying to save: Ex 17:3–4, Jn 8:59; 10:31; Acts 14:4–7; 19–20; 2 Cor
> 11:24–29
>
> Both were opposed by false prophets of depraved mind: 2 Tim 3:8; Ex
> 7:11–13, 1 Tim 6:3–5
>
> Both became fearful during their mission and needed reassuring in what
> to speak: Ex 6:11–13, Acts 18:9–10
>
> Paul shared with Christ, the function of being Moses’ replacement by
> removing the veil: Deuteronomy 18:18-19, Acts 3:19–24; 2 Cor 3:18–4:6