Have any saints and/or scholars noted parallels between Habakkuk and St. Peter?
I was reading the Office of Readings this morning and the reading was from the beginning of Habakkuk (assuming I'm on the right week, which I might not be). In any event, it was the first chapter of a book I'd never really paid much attention to and I was reflecting on it and it seemed to draw out a lot of motif's from the life of St. Peter

He scoffs at kings (when St. Peter says that Jesus shouldn't go to Jerusalem or wash his feet)
He gathers fish, like men
He is the rock readied for punishment (although Rock refers to God in this passage)
He brandishes the sword and might have slayed without mercy.
He was the rash man, but was justified because of his faith.

I don't see any intertext references in the New American Bible that suggest it, but I couldn't help but see it this morning and was wondering if there was anything to it.

I've been looking, but nothing so far...

@wyrsa - maybe it's a stretch, but I was sort of surprised before when I asked about Moses and St. Paul https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/89205/looking-for-works-comparing-moses-and-st-paul
